# Using same UriTemplate attribute for POST and GET operations WCF REST C#

Tags: wcf, rest, post, .net-3.5, get

I am getting a "Method not allowed." error from my WCF service when invoking a GET operation. I know why this is happening but can't understand why it is not allowed. I guess I might be doing something wrong. I am trying to use the same UriTemplate (attribute) structure for GET and POST. I am following a standard REST service convention:

```
GET - /api/v1/{entityType} - to get a list of {entityType} e.g. /api/v1/cars
POST - /api/v1/{entityType} - to insert an entity e.g /api/v1/car
```

```cs
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, 
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
        UriTemplate = "api/v1/{entityType}?skip={skip}&take={take}")]
List<Entity> GetEntityList(string entityType, int skip, int take);

[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", 
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, 
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
            UriTemplate = "api/v1/{entityType}")]
Entity InsertEntity(string entityType, Entity entity);
```

I understand that my UriTemplates are the same but why is this not allowed? Doesn't the server detect what operation I am trying to perform?

Comment: You don't describe the hosting environment for your service (IIS, Window service, ...) but it is possible that the service host is not configured to handle a GET or POST request. For example, IIS 7 by default won't accept PUT requests and gives a similar error.

Comment: Sorry about that I'm using IIS 7 and configured (was working by default) to accept `GET, POST, PUT` and `DELETE`. I came up with a workaround for the time being but will post it here as a solution once I see it works properly in production. The problem is the `{entityType}` parameter for `POST`. If I `PUT` or `GET` on `api/v1/{entityType}/{id}` it works well. It is `POST` that is causing the problem.